# How to put html inside of a select option value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to make something like a Visual Composer for a website, so one of the options that I want to include is to add an HTML code depending on what you selected on a select item, to do so I have to put each HTML on the value of the option but I can´t find the way to do so :(

This is what I tried to do:

```
<select ng-model="product1.stars">
  <option  value="<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>" >
  </option>
</select>
```

Please help me with this!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `bs-select` and `bs-options` directives from [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)

HTML

```
  <div class="bs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;" append-source>

    <label>Single select:&nbsp;</label>
    <button type="button" 
            class="btn btn-default" 
            ng-model="selectedIcon"
            data-html="1" 
            bs-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons"
            bs-select>
      Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

JS

```
app.controller('SelectDemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.selectedIcon = 'Gear';
  $scope.icons = [
    {value: 'Gear', label: '<i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Gear'},
    {value: 'Globe', label: '<i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Globe'},
    {value: 'Heart', label: '<i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Heart'},
    {value: 'Camera', label: '<i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Camera'}
  ];

});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/b6t0spVNitCBkT8ZZVxt?p=preview)